# Compilation error in C++ Possibly Namespace problems

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I believe my problem is very fundamental, but I am not finding a solution to it. I have tried several workarounds. The errors I'm getting are a very long list of "no matching function call to's". I am pretty sure it has to do with how I'm working with namespaces, but looking online it seems like I am formatting it correctly. The namespace thing is a requirement for an assignment so I cannot remove it.

**Code:**

```
namespace complexSpc{
    class complex
    {
    public:

        friend complex operator*(complex &, complex &);
    };
}
```

At the bottom of my program, I define my class members. They are not within a namespace block. I tried to do that but it didn't fix anything. I also tried to move the definitions so they are defined when they are declared.

```
    complexSpc::complex complexSpc :: operator*(complexSpc::complex & first, complexSpc::complex & second)
{
    complexSpc::complex t1 = complexSpc::complex(first.real() * second.real(), first.imag() * second.imag());

    return t1;
}
```

The error produced for this is like so:

complexFix.cpp:183: error: no matching function for call to ‘complexSpc::complex                                                                                                                     ::complex(complexSpc::complex)’

Someone has asked if I have a copy constructor. I do. It is declared in the namespace and defined like so:

```
complex(complex &);


complexSpc::complex::complex(complexSpc::complex & copy)
{
    member1 = copy.real();
    member2 = copy.imag();
    return;
}
```

Comment: reduce it to 1 operator and post the error.

Comment: Reduced. Sorry about that

Comment: Looks like you're simply missing a definition for the copy constructor of `complex`. Also for implementation files, I think it's OK to say `using namespace complexSpc;` in the beginning, instead of repeating it on each and every implementation.

Comment: This is my copy constructor: complex(complex &);
complexSpc::complex::complex(complexSpc::complex & copy)
{
 member1 = copy.real();
 member2 = copy.imag();
 return;
}

Comment: You'll have to use `complex(const complex& rhs)` as signature of the copy constructor (`return` is not needed).

Comment: What you have posted produces totally different compilation errors from what is claimed in the post. You have reduced your original code too much. Please post code that people can compile and see the exact same error you see.

Comment: I'm sorry if I dont follow, but just like this? complexSpc::complex::complex(complexSpc::const complex& rhs)
{
 member1 = rhs.real();
 member2 = rhs.imag();
}

Comment: Why are you using the getter methods here, you can simply take direct copies from `rhs.member1`, `rhs.member2`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of your copy constructor to:

```
complexSpc::complex::complex(const complexSpc::complex & copy);
```

To allow rvalues of complex being copied on the return statement of your operator definition.

**Note** that you'll have to stick to this principle for your operator signatures also, to be able to use them in combined operations:

```
complexSpc::complex complexSpc :: operator*
    ( const complexSpc::complex & first
    , const complexSpc::complex & second
    );
```

Most probably this should fix most of your remaining errors.

Comment: i changed the constructor as you said, but do I have to change the definition too? Sorry, i'm a beginner at this stuff

Comment: Yup! They have always to have consistent signatures of course.

Comment: but it looks identical to what you wrote to my untrained eyes. i wish i could pastebin the whole code and the whole error list. would fixing the copy constructor fix all of the errors? the errors are just a long list of the same thing which is why i suspected namespace issues

Comment: Sorry you're right. Did it correctly in my comment, but not for the answer. Fixed it!

Comment: so just the word const?

Comment: Yes! Small word but **very** important.

Comment: there's so many errors, that i dont know if it fixed anything or not. the problem is that it built consistently on visual studio but not the compiler for my class...

Comment: At least it should fix the error that you have originally posted.

Comment: @user3020610 Unfortunately Visual Studio is a very permissive compiler and allows many things that aren't really allowed in C++. In terms of grades you'll probably be best off using the compiler that the class graders are using, and in terms of learning C++ you're best off using the strictest compiler you can find (or even using several different compilers at once).

Comment: i believe it has. there are fewer errors now. for example: complexNumbers.cpp:182: error: ‘complexSpc::complex complexSpc::operator*(complexSpc::complex&, complexSpc::complex&)’ should have been declared inside ‘complexSpc’

Answer (score 1):

> complexFix.cpp:183: error: no matching function for call to ‘complexSpc::complex ::complex(complexSpc::complex)’

Your original code includes the line:

```
complexSpc::complex t1 = complexSpc::complex(member1 + second.real(), member2 + second.imag());
```

Which constructs a temporary and then copy-constructs `t1` with it. However your copy constsructor is declared:

```
complex(complex &);
```

Which means it cannot take temporaries as arguments, because non-const (lvalue) references are not permitted to bind to temporary objects. *Note: Visual Studio has an extension which does allow temporaries to bind to non-const lvalue references, so it won't catch this error.*

const references are allowed to bind to temporaries, so if you change the copy constructor to:

```
complex(complex const &);
```

Then the compiler will be able to find the matching function it's looking for in that error message.

Also note that there are many other functions in your code with non-const reference parameters. Those may not be causing errors yet as you're not using those functions with temporaries, but they will have to be updated as well in order to work with temporaries.

---

> complexNumbers.cpp:182: error: ‘complexSpc::complex complexSpc::operator*(complexSpc::complex&, complexSpc::complex&)’ should have been declared inside ‘complexSpc’

I believe this is actually a bug in the compiler. The friend declarations inside the class should be sufficient, however gcc doesn't appear to properly handle that in all cases. A workaround is to declare those friend functions it's erroring on a second time, but outside the class:

```
namespace N {
  class C {
    friend void f();
  };
  void f(); // workaround.
}
void N::f() {}
```

Comment: i tried defining it within the braces but it did not fix anything

Comment: there are many fewer errors now. the ones i see now from the wall of text are pretty much all like this one: complexNumbers.cpp:182: error: ‘complexSpc::complex complexSpc::operator*(complexSpc::complex&, complexSpc::complex&)’ should have been declared inside ‘complexSpc’